# C question: single dereference on a void** double indirection pointer

Tags: c, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, void, void-pointers

I got this message:

```
expected 'void **' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

when I tried to compile something similar to this:

```
void myfree( void **v )
{
    if( !v || !*v )
        return;

    free( *v );
    *v = NULL;

    return;
}
```

I found what I think is a solution after reading this question on stack overflow:
[Avoid incompatible pointer warning when dealing with double-indirection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943983/avoid-incompatible-pointer-warning-when-dealing-with-double-indirection)

So I adjusted to something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myfree( void *x )
{
    void **v = x;

    if( !v || !*v )
        return;

    free( *v );
    *v = NULL;

    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char *test;

    if( ( test = malloc( 1 ) ) )
    {
        printf( "before: %p\n", test );
        myfree( &test );
        printf( "after: %p\n", test );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is this legal C? I am dereferencing a void pointer aren't I?

Thanks guys


**EDIT 12/10/2010 4:45PM EST:**
As it has been pointed out `free(NULL)` is safe and covered by the C standard. Also, as discussed below my example above is not legal C. See caf's answer, Zack's answer, and my own answer.

Therefore it's going to be easier for me to initalize any to-be-malloc'd pointers as NULL and then later on to just free() and NULL out directly in the code:

```
free( pointer );
pointer = NULL;
```

The reason I was checking for NULL in myfree() like I did was because of my experiences with fclose(). `fclose(NULL)` can segfault depending on platform (eg xpsp3 msvcrt.dll 7.0.2600.5512) and so I had assumed (mistakenly) the same thing could happen with free(). I had figured rather than clutter up my code with if statements I could better implement in a function.

Thanks everyone for all the good discussion

Comment: Some will call me a heathen but I would just use `define myfree(x) do { free(x); x = NULL } while(0)`

Comment: You are not dereferencing a 'pointer to void'.  You are dereferencing a 'pointer to pointer to void', which is perfectly legal.

Comment: Actually, I want to correct my previous macro: `#define myfree(x) do { void **tmp_ = &x; free(*tmp_); *tmp_ = NULL; } while(0)` (I thought there wasn't a way to avoid double evaluation of `x` but there is!)

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Your new macro has the same problem as the OPs code - only `void *` values can now be legally passed as `x`.  Under GCC you could use `typeof(x) *tmp_ = &x;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is **not** legal C, unless you pass the address of a `void *` object to `myfree()` (so you might as well just keep your original definition).

The reason is that in your example, an object of type `char *` (the object declared as `test` in `main()`) is modified through an lvalue of type `void *` (the lvalue `*v` in `myfree()`).  §6.5 of the C standard states:

> 7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of
>       the following types:
>
> ```
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of 
> the object,
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective
> type of the object,
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified
> version of the effective type of the object,
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
> types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate
> or contained union), or
> — a character type.
> ```

Since `void *` and `char *` are not compatible types, this constraint has been broken.  The condition for two pointer types to be compatible is described in §6.7.5.1:

> For two pointer types to be
>   compatible, both shall be identically
>   qualified and both shall be pointers
>   to compatible types.

To achieve the effect you want, you must use a macro:

```
#define MYFREE(p) (free(p), (p) = NULL)
```

(There is no need to check for `NULL`, since `free(NULL)` is legal.  Note that this macro evaluates `p` twice).

Comment: It is required for *any* pointer-to-object to be convertible to `void *` and back without loss of information; thus clearing a pointer-to-object via a `void *` alias is overwhelmingly likely to DTRT even when not all pointers have the same representation.  The only case where it mightn't is if the *null pointer constant* is not all-bits-zero for all pointer-to-object types, but AFAIK nobody - truly nobody - does that anymore.  I suppose you might also have to worry about overoptimization due to the type-based aliasing rules, feh.

Comment: Further, it occurs to me that the semantics of `malloc` and `free` themselves pretty much require the null pointer constant to be the same bit pattern for all pointers-to-object.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: I only have the draft C standard revision as of June 2010 on this computer.  In that document, the relevant text is in §6.3.2.3 (Conversions: Pointers), paragraph 1 states quite baldly "A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer."

Comment: @ZacK: §6.2.5 states explicitly *"Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."*.  "overwhelmingly likely to DTRT" and "legal C" are very different things.  Additionally, the semantics of `malloc` and `free` hold no implications about the bit patterns of pointers, since when they are used correctly all the conversions to and from `void *` are done "in front of the compiler", so it can apply whatever transformations are necessary.  The same is true of the comparison guarantee - the conversions in this case are done in full view of the compiler.

Comment: caf: consider "`double *foo = 0; free(foo);`" -- strictly conforming, and the call to `free` is required to be a no-op. Anyway, despite having been a compiler guy, I'm on the side of the systems hackers when C is concerned: if your code will almost surely DTRT on all platforms of interest, then I don't care if it's strictly conforming or not, it's legitimate C.  Especially when there is no strictly-conforming way to achieve the desired result, as here (your macro does not qualify because it evaluates `p` twice).

Comment: @Zack: In this case, the compiler sees that `0` is being stored in an object of type `double *`, so it can do the necessary magic to store the bit pattern of a `double *` null pointer in `foo`.  In the call to free, the argument to `free` is a `void *`, so again the compiler has the opportunity to insert the necessary code to convert a `double *` to `void *`, including converting the bit pattern of a null pointer in the former into the bit pattern of a null pointer in the latter.

Comment: @Zack you are confusing two things. One: Converting a `double*` to a `void*` (what you do). Two: Treating a `double*` as if it was a `void*` - in other words, type punning (what he does, and what is undefined behavior).

Comment: I understand perfectly that writing to a `double*` through a `void*` alias is undefined behavior.  I just don't think it's the kind of undefined behavior that people need to be warned away from doing, because it's not going to be trouble in real life.  In general I think folks here err a bit too far on the side of warning people away from not-strictly-conforming-but-perfectly-reliable-in-practice constructs.

Comment: @Zack: I'm not so sure about the reliability in later versions of gcc - indeed, the OPs code results in the warning `x.c:12: warning: dereferencing pointer 'v' does break strict-aliasing rules` when compiled with `-O3` on gcc 4.

Comment: @caf: What might gcc4 do with that information? It could assume that the call to `myfree` did not modify the value of the pointer variable whose address was taken. But we just passed that value to `free`. Therefore if the program does anything that depends on gcc *not* making that assumption, it is already incorrect (it is accessing a freed heap object). ...Unless the program is relying on `myfree` to set things up so a future check indicates that the variable contains a null pointer. That might break. Or I suppose gcc might even be allowed to delete the call to `free`. Bleah.

Comment: It occurred to me on the way home that part of the problem could be eliminated by converting to `char **` rather than `void **` on the way in, and clearing the pointer with `memset`.  That exchanges one type of UB for another (there being no guarantee that the representation of any null pointer is all-bits-zero) but representation-of-pointer UB is far less likely to cause trouble than TBAA overoptimization is.  Unfortunately, it doesn't improve the TBAA situation with the actual call to `free`, I think.

Comment: @caf re your comments about `void *` and `char *` not being compatible types. I read in §6.2.5 part 27 the following: *A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.* so I am wondering more about this, whether that conflicts with what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: @Anonymous Question Guy: It's true that `void *` and `char *` are required to have the same representation and alignment requirements, but that doesn't make them *compatible types*, which has a specific definition.  I tend to agree that either there should be an exception to make `void *` and `char *` compatible types, or an exception allowing `void *` objects to be accessed through `char *` lvalues and vice-versa, to give the requirement in §6.2.5 its full intended effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly legal but can get confusing for other people who read your code.

You could also use casting to eliminate the warning:

```
myfree((void **)&rest);
```

This is more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

In C you have no choice but to introduce a cast somewhere in here.  I would use a macro to ensure that things were done correctly at the call site:

```
void
myfree_(void **ptr)
{
    if (!ptr || !*ptr) return;
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = 0;
}
#define myfree(ptr) myfree_((void **)&(ptr))
```

[You could actually name both the function and the macro "myfree", thanks to C's no-infinite-macro-recursion rules!  But it would be confusing for human readers.  Per the long discussion below caf's answer, I will also stipulate that the statement `*ptr = 0` here modifies an object of unknown type through a `void**` alias, which is runtime-undefined behavior -- however, my informed opinion is, it will not cause problems in practice, and it's the least bad option available in plain C; caf's macro that evaluates its argument twice seems far more likely (to me) to cause real problems.]

In C++ you could use a template function, which is better on three counts: it avoids needing to take the address of anything at the call site, it doesn't break type correctness, and you will get a compile-time error instead of a run-time crash if you accidentally pass a non-pointer to `myfree`.

```
template <typename T>
void
myfree(T*& ptr)
{
    free((void *)ptr);
    ptr = 0;
}
```

But of course in C++ you have even better options available, such as smart pointer and container classes.

It should, finally, be mentioned that skilled C programmers eschew this kind of wrapper, because it does not help you when there's another copy of the pointer to the memory you just freed hanging around somewhere -- and that's exactly when you need help.

Comment: I usually write the function and macro with the same names, and when I call the function (in the macro or elsewhere) I write it as `(myfree)(x);`, which a) disables the preprocessor macro expansion, b) clarifies that I'm not calling the macro, and c) allows you to pass `myfree` (instead of `myfree_`) as a function pointer.

Comment: Oooh, I like the idea of hiding the cast inside a macro. I like your way here much better than hiding the setting to NULL inside a macro, because your way here preserves the address (&) operator, which is an important visual cue that the pointer will change (e.g., be zeroed out).

Comment: Erm, I take that back. Your `myfree_((void **)&(ptr))` doesn't preserve the `&` address operator in the calling source — it still hides it in the macro. How about defining `myfree` as `myfree_((void **)(ptr))` so that the user says `myfree(&ptr)` rather than `myfree(ptr)`? That seems preferable to me.

Comment: If I were going to do this at all (which, in fact, I wouldn't -- see the last paragraph of the answer) I would consider it more important to make sure that the address is always taken than to have the & be visible in the source code.  I may be saying this because I'm used to C++ nowadays, and by-reference out-parameters don't have any such visual clue.

Answer (score 1):

***caf's answer is correct: No, it's not legal***. And as Zack points out breaking the law in this way is apparently least likely to cause problems.

I found what appears to be another solution in the [comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 4.9](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html), which notes that an intermediate void value has to be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myfree( void **v )
{
    if( !v )
        return;

    free( *v );
    *v = NULL;

    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    double *num;

    if( ( num = malloc( sizeof( double ) ) ) )
    {
        printf( "before: %p\n", num );

        {
            void *temp = num;
            myfree( &temp );
            num = temp;
        }

        printf( "after: %p\n", num );
    }

    return 0;
}
```